# SSIS 2012 Continuous Integration with TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, ssis, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, continuous-deployment

I’ve been reading some articles (this one in particular: http://speaksql.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/a-journey-to-db-deployment-automaton-ssis-build-using-msbuild/) about using msbuild.exe to build and deploy an SSIS package (.ispac). I had no problem with that from my computer which has all the required assemblies, and only using the msbuild.exe command.

Once I tried to use the TFS Build Server I had some problems. First I realized that using a project with msbuild.exe (SSIS.MSBuild.proj) was not recommended with TFS 2013 since it was used with TFS 2008 and 2010. Anyway, I just wanted to make it work and it sounded plausible, but I had to use the TFSBuild.proj. That was not a problem, but my next problem was that the project I was being using (Microsoft SQL Server Community Samples: Integration Services) references a SQL Server assembly (Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS) which is not installed on my build server.

Then I realized that even if I managed to install that assembly on the gac, or referenced it on a relative path I would have a bigger problem next, I am using custom activities on my packages which I need to install using gacutil.exe on the host server, and I was wondering how to install, remotely, those dll.

That’s when I started to lose faith, and here I am, is there an “easy” way to implement continuous integration for SSIS packages without installing third party tools (http://remotegacutil.codeplex.com/ for example), and adding missing assemblies to the gac of a build server?

Did any of you have a similar issue? Did you solve it? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use devenv.exe to build the ispac. Add an invoke process task and call out to devenv.
[image: Add an Invoke Process to the workflow]

Add an Invoke Process to the Build Template, the one above shows a Sequence container, which assigns the path to the correct version of DeVenv to call, VS2010 /12 /13 etc. this is shown as hard coded but can be put into an argument, so it can be populated in individual build definitions. the one you can't see clearly is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com"

Next is the invoke Process, this call out to the specified devenv.exe and passes arguments used to build the ISPAC file.

[image: Call Devenv.exe and Pass Arguments]

The arguments are passed in **localProject** would get you the actual project you wanted to build in previous versions, you may have to do something different for 2013, due to the changes to the new templates.

this gives a TFS2012 way of doing it, as i say you may have to do something different to get the project that you want to build under 2013, but the build will run and an .ISPAC file will be generated.

at this point i would deploy the ISPAC using powershell, you may want to add additional scripts to the powershell calls to handle creating the SSIS Catalog and scheduling of the job.

deploying with Powershell can be found here [Deploying ISPAC's with Powershell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2011/11/17/ssis-and-powershell-in-sql-server-2012.aspx)

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, that does not answer my question about remotely installing my custom tasks on the gac. But it may answer my question about the ManagedDTS assembly. I think I will need a 2010 version of Visual Studio, which is not and will not be installed on the build server.

Comment: Could you expound upon `use devenv.exe` to help future readers know precisely how they'd use it to create an ispac. Currently, your answer is a comment

Comment: expanded the description of how to call devenv from a build template

Comment: @ El Barto why would you not install vs on the build server?

Comment: Thanks for the details on how to call devenv. I still don't know how to manage the remote installation of my custom tasks on the gac. I can't install vs simply because where I work at this moment they can't see the point of having to install an additional vs on a machine that is only meant to build. Furthermore, it worked fine, until ssis came in. I wonder when Microsoft will catch up with ssis…

Comment: VS installed on the build server will allow for code coverage collection as well, you don't need an additional licence on the build server. you can use a similar method with devenv to do SSAS aswell with the output being a .asadatabase file. so your custom activities are being consumed by your SSIS package? is that correct

Comment: I'll try to see what I can do about vs on the build server. And yes, my custom activities are consumed by my packages.

Comment: for deploying to the GAC you could also use powershell, have a look at http://blog.goverco.com/2012/04/use-powershell-to-put-your-assemblies.html

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time, this deserves to be marked as an answer, I will do the rest and make it all work (I hope). Thanks again.